# Excel formula to show multiple cell address or row locations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the following formula, which returns a numeric value:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A176="Thing1")*(B3:B176="Thing2")*(C3:C176="Thing3")*(U3:U176="No"))
```

However, I'd like to also know the cell address or row location of each item that meets the criteria. Googling took me to the `address()`, `index()`, and `vlookup()` functions, but I haven't had any tinkering luck thus far.

I'm only able to get a single cell address as a result. It sounds like an "If/Then" job, but I haven't tried Excel's related functions yet.

Comment: Which do you want? Cell address or row number? Where do you want the results? In a single cell, e.g. comma-separated? If so, this will require VBA. If not, and you're happy with each return to go in its own cell, this is doable using worksheet formulas alone.

Comment: Good morning; having each return in its own cell is fine, and I'd prefer the row, although cell address is ok as well.

Comment: Thanks. Which version of Excel is this for?

Comment: Do you want all those information listed in one cell? If yes, then you would need an array formula capable `CONCATENATE()` or `CONCATENATEIFS()` function which unfortunately doesn't exist. Have a look e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639868/vba-user-defined-function-for-concatenate-if-by-rows

Comment: @XOR, I'm using multiple versions - Office 2011 on Mac, and Office 2010/13 on Windows.

Comment: @Mate, it doesn't have to be listed in the same cell. I took a peek at the link you provided, and that solution was heading in a different direction, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick an unused column, say **V**, in **V3** enter:

```
=IF(AND(A3="Thing1",B3="Thing2",C3="thing3",U3="No"),ROW(),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

and if you want a nice condensed list with no spaces, then in **W3** enter the *array formula*:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($V$3:$V$176,SMALL((IF(LEN($V$3:$V$176),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($V$3:$V$176))))),ROW(V1)),1),"")
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gary, this is very close to what I envisioned; it does the job nicely though, the results are in line with what I need. Thanks!